# Parsing package versions with wildcards for comparison in PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, shopware, semantic-versioning

I am trying to compare the package version such as `^6.1||^6.2||^6.3` using `\Composer\Semver\VersionParser` but am not getting the expected result.

I am breaking down the version like so

```
            $currentVersion = '6.3';
            $requiredPackage = '^6.1||^6.2||^6.3';
            $compatibleVersions = explode('||', $requiredPackage);
            $lowestSupported = ltrim(current($compatibleVersions), '^');
            $highestSupported = ltrim(end($compatibleVersions), '^');

            $parser = new VersionParser();
            $lowestSupported = $parser->normalize($lowestSupported);
            $highestSupported = $parser->normalize($highestSupported);

            $isLower = version_compare($currentVersion, $lowestSupported, '<');
            $isHigher = version_compare($currentVersion, $highestSupported, '>');

            if ($isLower || $isHigher) {
                return false;
            }
```

This works fine for cases where `$currentVersion` is 6.3, but I think it would fail for `6.3.4.0` because although `^6.3` matches the package, but since `VersionParser` normalizes the version `6.3` as `6.3.0.0` instead, and it cannot parse the `^6.3` correctly to allow `6.3.4.0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could `vierbergenlars/php-semver` help you?

Comment: Also, how is this related to Shopware?

Comment: Next up: if you already use `composer/semver`'s parser, why not also use their comparator?

Comment: It is not directly related to shopware, but I need to use the already existing libraries inside Shopware, which is why I had tagged it. Can you point me to the comparator package and I will check it out if it exists in the installation. Is there not a generic PHP solution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/composer/semver contains all relevant information. If you already use the version parser, you don't need to install anything else

Comment: How exactly does this relate to semantic versioning? The [SemVer standard](https://semver.org) requires the Major.Minor.Patch triple, no quads allowed.

Comment: @jwdonahue you are right, but I had tagged #shopware in the question as well due to their versioning strategy: https://www.shopware.com/en/news/shopware-6-versioning-strategy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it using Nico Haase's suggestion as following:

```
$isLower = Comparator::lessThan($currentVersion, $lowestSupported);
$isHigher = Comparator::greaterThan($highestSupported, $currentVersion);
```